# What would you consider a decent spec for a developer desktop?

Tags: ipc

What would people assume is a good development pc spec?
I'm not looking for how cheap can I get away nor for what would be the ultimate machine.

We speaking java server side development and Ajax web development. Some DB work.

Comment: Buying the cheapest of everything will be fine except for the hard drive - spend the money on a good SSD, it's well worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest focusing on items that verifiably improve developer productivity (and avoid things that hinder productivity).

1. Two monitors of decent size
2. Developer's choice of mouse/keyboard
3. Hard drive should be fast (7200RPM+) and large enough to host VMs, developer software, etc. (100GB+)
4. 64-bit OS with plenty of RAM (2GB minimum)
5. Avoid old architecture (i.e. don't go older than Core 2)
6. Avoid loading software that will slow down your developer (certain anti-virus solutions come to mind)
7. Be willing to purchase developer tools that would help the developer do their jobs faster and with better accuracy

I'm actually researching this myself as I'm wanting to build a machine at home that will allow me to experiment with development on a variety of platforms.

Comment: all good for me - but min 4GB RAM... preferably even more.

Comment: My preference is for 4GB - but that's because my development tools are resource-hungry.  I figure it's possible that Java tools are slimmer.

Comment: At least 16 GB RAM, 512 GB SSD, and at least 4 independent cores operating at or above 2.5 GHz

Answer (score 0):

For a desktop? I'd say you probably wouldn't need much, probably a 500$ one (without screen) would be more than enough. I've thrown in a link to a computer I think would work just as an example:

[http://www.amazon.com/Acer-AspireRevo-AR1600-U910H-Desktop-Windows/dp/B002O3W44Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=pc&qid=1278601805&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002O3W44Q) (maybe a bit too slow)

[http://www.amazon.com/HP-Pavilion-Slimline-s5510f-Desktop/dp/B003L0OUMU/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&s=pc&qid=1278601852&sr=1-4(that](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003L0OUMU) one looks like one of the better choices)

I honestly don't think you need a great computer if all your using it for is programming. in the way of actual specs:

- minimum dual core
- minimum 2 gigs ram
- graphics card doesn't matter
- minimum 100 gig hard drive, you can always throw on an external drive if you run out.

Answer (score 0):

RAM 2GB minimum as you'll probably run a Java IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans), an application server and a database.

Answer (score 0):

yipes - i wouldn't go below 4GB ram.  especially if you will be doing anything real.